# get words from string using preg_split in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get words from string in php using preg_split like this:

```
$result = preg_split('/[^A-Za-z]+/', $text)
```

but this doesn't work, some words are split,
what am I doing wrong?

Edit: the fact is it doesn't work with russian text = "фыва ывафы фываф";

```
$result = preg_split('/[^А-яа-я]+/', $text)
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? Perhaps show us what `$text` looks like and what you expect `$result` to contain?

Comment: $text = "As sdf fdasf", $result = array("A", " ");

Comment: @Herokiller: So? That splits into `["As", "sdf", "fdasf"]` just fine.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I get Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 
)

Comment: @Herokiller in the comment, you wrote $result = array("A"," ");

Comment: @TimPietzcker It doesn't work with russian symbols, like $result = preg_split('/[^А-яа-я]+/', $text)

Comment: So why didn't you say so? Your example strings didn't contain any Russian letters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[^A-Za-z]` only takes ASCII letters into account. You need to split on Unicode non-letters:

```
$result = preg_split('/\P{L}+/u', $subject);
```

`[^А-Яа-я]+` won't work either because in the Unicode character set, `А` (0x0410) is not the first Kyrillian letter, and `я` (0x044F) is not the last one. It appears these honors go to `Ё` (0x0401) and `ӹ` (0x04F9). I don't know Russian at all, so I can't speculate on why this is so.

You can check this easily using your character map program:

[image: screenshot charmap]

Comment: thank you, but why doesn't it work with only russian string like $result = preg_split('/[^А-яа-я]+/', $text) ?

Comment: `A-я` is not a useful character range - there are a lot of characters between `Z` (Unicode 0x005A)  and `Ё` (0x0401, the first kyrillian letter in Unicode) that you don't want in that range. Also, the last kyrillian letter appears to be `ӹ`.

Comment: is a kyrillian 'A' the same as latin 'A'?

Comment: No, it isn't. They just look identical but have different codepoints: `A` (ASCII, 0x0041), `Α` (Greek, 0x0390), `A` (Kyrillian, 0x0410) etc. ...ah, now I get it: Yours was a Kyrillian A, not an ASCII A? OK, I will edit my answer to explain that better.

Comment: but I use kyrillian 'A' in A-Яa-я, so shouldn't it work for kyrillian only text(with letters in range of А-Я)?

Comment: btw, according to this map it should work, but it somehow splits on some characters which are inside green field

Comment: Then that's probably a special PHP oddity: Does it work if you use the `/u` Unicode modifier, as in `'/[^А-я]+/u'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str ="As sdf fdasf";
$result = preg_split('/[\b ]/', $str);
```

edit:

```
$result = preg_split('/\b\s+/', $str); //this is not for Unicode
```

Comment: You can't use `\b` inside a character class. (Well, you can, but it will not mean "word boundary" but "backspace")